different verions of vs code opens using from dash and terminal
facing strange issue in ubuntu 24.04
VS Code installed since long (do not remember whether installed using snap or using .deb package, although recently installed using package code_1.93.1-1726079302_amd64.deb)
whicle ls -l /var/lib/snapd/snaps does not list the code in its output but whereis display its
> whereis code
code: /usr/bin/code /usr/share/code /snap/bin/code
> which code
/usr/bin/code


below is the screenshot of above command

and pinned the vs code using used Pin to Dash in left panel on dekstop
Now when open it from Dash, it open with the older version 1.92
and when open using terminal, using code . ; it openes the latest version 1.93
while checking code -v in termianl it shows 1.92
so my issue is how to make sure that same version ( latest ) opense and keep it auto updated  using diffrent approach.
Note: added vs code repository in update but still when open from dash , it keep saying update now while its is already in latest version


What is the result of which code?

which code outputs /usr/bin/code while whereis gives whereis code gives
code: /usr/bin/code /usr/share/code /snap/bin/code

It seems that you have the both the snap version and the apt version installed.
You can remove the snap version with
sudo snap remove code


that gives error ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/snap/code'

Can you try removing it from the Ubuntu app store, using GUI?

it is not installed when check on App Center; it show install button enabled
